# Change sudoers file at build time Yocto Project 2.0

Tags: linux, yocto

I am using yocto project (QorIQ SDK 2.0) to create my operating system and I want to add the following lines to the `sudoers` file at compile time:

```
*##My extra rules*
Cmnd_Alias DATE=/bin/date
%test ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: DATE
```

I have tried to find the compilation 'sources' of this file, in yocto it is contained inside a folder called 'sudo' whose path is (/home/user/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/sources/meta-selinux/recipes-extended) but the files in this folder only contain links to files of type .so and there is no type of file that I can modify and add my rules

Comment: If it's easier, consider adding a file into /etc/sudoers.d; your main sudoers file may already #include files from there.

Comment: /etc/sudoers.d does not exist in the source files for the compilation of the system with yocto project

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem with this SDK, we don't know it is problem of NXP but we can't update the SDK and we have to much problem to the Linux that generated with this SDK.

I recommend to you to downgrade to 1.8, it's the SDK to we are using now to developed.

We are waiting that they repair this SDK because I only read and have bugs with this SDK.

Comment: I use both SDK but for this I want to develop in the 2.0 SDK. Anyway what I want to do, I do not know how to do it from SDK 1.8. That would not solve my doubt.

Comment: When you install the SDK, are you using a superuser? If it's a superuser, you might have a permissions error when you want to use bitbake and that. I had a similar error and my solution was to use it to install as a normal user.